# Не применим или неприменим?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

На сегодняшний день ни один вид товаров, предусмотренный в торговом каталоге, к данной ситуации не применим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку есть зависимые слова, правильно раздельно, как вы и написали: *ни один не применим.*